# Set value not working on multiple select dropdowns in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm working on codeigniter where i'm using set_value function to get the value of dropdown

```
$category_id = $this->form_validation->set_value('Category[]');
```

but the issue is it is not working on multiple select. It is working where single value is selected.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter, select dropdown works with `set_select()` not `set_value()`

Reference: [Codeigniter Form Helper Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select)

Can you try using `set_select()`?